# How to make sure you are getting the most out of your SSD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, speed

Just got my hands on a 60gb OCZ Vertex 2 SSD - Claims to have 285/275 write and read speeds. However when testing with AS SSD Benchmark im getting about 140/90.

**System**:

- Windows 7 32-Bit
- 60gb SSD - TRIM enabled 7.4 Windows
  Rating
- 2.6ghz Core 2 Duo
- 4gb Ram

Any pointers to improve the speed/ any ideas why it isnt performing as well as suggested. Got it form ebuyer, comments seem to suggest others are having no problem hitting the higher end of the read/write speeds.---

Answer (score 2):

I know AHCI plays a part in SSD speed. Have you turned it on in BIOS? I also know that many suggest turning it on before you actually install Windows 7 to get better performance. My guess is this will up your speed at least a bit.

Comment: Plus you can look at the SATA channel and see if it's 1.5Gbps, 3Gbps or 6Gbps.

Answer (score 1):

A few websites have helped me in my search for Windows 7 SSD tweaks as I have a 40GB Intel X25-V for performance increase over a 1TB WD10EARS harddrive:

[Superuser has a page on some SSD tweaks.](https://superuser.com/questions/137817/best-ssd-tweaks-for-windows-7)

[My Dell Mini](http://www.mydellmini.com/forum/windows-7/2441-windows-7-ultimate-solid-state-drive-speed-tweaks.html) has a website with a load of SSD tweaks that also apply to 2.5" SSDs and PCIe SSD cards.

[Crucial also has a thread in their forums](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?49779-SSD-Tweak-Utility) devoted to some SSD tweaks.